# How do I put a Google Chart inside Fusion Table Map's Info Window?

Tags: html, ajax, google-maps, google-visualization, google-fusion-tables

I want to put a Google Chart inside the info window of the Fusion Table's Map.

Link to the code of Google Chart: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start

I inserted that code inside the info window custom layout but it wouldn't recognize the line

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
```

because it thinks the curly braces refer to a data column.

Is there other ways I can put a Google Chart inside the info window?

Thanks!

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks for redirecting me.

Answer (score 0):

Make a [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) map with a FusionTablesLayer.  Add an event listener on the [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer) that opens your infowindow containing the chart.

If you click on the map tab in the FusionTables User Interface, choose the "Publish..." menu entry, there is an option to get the required HTML and Javascript ("Get HTML and JavaScript") to make a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map to start with.

Comment: I only saw HTML and URL links, and the HTML only shows the table, no map. but the e-tag (?) in the URL lets me get the map so that's nice.

Comment: if you click on the "HTML and JavaScript" link/arrow, it opens the HTML to create a map from your fusion table.  You can add the custom infowindow there.